# PowerShell 5.0 DSC and Imports

Tags: powershell, dsc, powershell-5.0

I want to define a single configuration that uses Install-Package to install xSystemSecurity and then import it and define a resource that disable IE ESC.

It this possible to do in a single Configuration with a Script Resouce and a xSystemSecurity Resource?

As soon as I try to import xSystemSecurity at the top of the Configuration, DSC blows up because it's not installed yet.

Answer (score 2):

DSC validates all resources in a configuration *before* it applies *any* changes. In order to do this, all resources must already be present on the box or available from a pull server. This means that you can't both install and use a resource in the same configuration. The best solution is to use the pull server to deploy the resource. If you can't use the pull server, then you have to use a 2 step process.

Comment: Thanks. That's a pretty major bummer considering MS's new package manager which makes it easy to Install-Package for DSC resources...

Answer (score 1):

Here is an easy way to setup a module repository using a file share http://nanalakshmanan.com/blog/Push-Config-Pull-Module/ Once setup your configuration should work as DSC can pull down the required module from the file share